# Query not working in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///dept_emp.csv" AS row
MATCH (emp_no:Employee {emp_no: row.emp_no})
MATCH (dept_no:departments {dept_no: row.dept_no})
MERGE(Employee)-[:belongs_to{from_date: row.from_date,to_date: 
row.to_date}]->(departments);
```

i want to make a relationship with properties using this query the structure of node

employee is

```
[
gender  M
emp_no  10001
birth_date  1953-09-02
last_name   Facello
hire_date   1986-06-26
first_name  Georgi

]
```

node departements is

```
[
dept_no d009
dept_name   Customer Service
]
```

structure of file 
dept_emp.csv is

```
(
emp_no  dept_name   from_date   to_date
)
```

the ide does'nt showing an error just start processing and after 6 hour still processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be a bit confused about match syntax, for which part is the variable, and which is the node label.

```
MATCH (emp_no:Employee {emp_no: row.emp_no})
```

In the above match, `:Employee` is the label of the node. `emp_no` is the variable bound to the :Employee node that is matched.

Later in the query, you have this:

```
MERGE(Employee)-[:belongs_to{from_date: row.from_date,to_date: 
row.to_date}]->(departments);
```

The problem here is that `Employee` and `departments` don't refer to anything you've matched to previously, this is the first occurrence of these variables, and that will throw off what this MERGE is doing. As it is, it is checking all relationships between all nodes (and doing this for every row in your CSV), looking for :belongs_to relationships with the given date properties.

I suggest you stop the query (by killing Neo4j if necessary) cleaning up the data (in case it needs it) and trying again, but try a MERGE with the variables you previously bound:

```
MERGE(emp_no)-[:belongs_to{from_date: row.from_date,to_date: 
row.to_date}]->(dept_no);
```

Make sure you have indexes or unique constraints on :Employee(emp_no) and :departments(dept_no) for fast matching.